# Diversity of opinions on user input in regard to MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, view, controller

Some articles on the MVC model topic state user actions go directly into `Controller`:

- http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp
- http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/
- http://geekswithblogs.net/dlussier/archive/2009/11/21/136454.aspx

Others state that user actions first go into the `View`:

- http://www.infoworld.com/article/2926003/microsoft-net/exploring-the-mvc-mvp-and-mvvm-design-patterns.html
- https://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/mvc-vs-mvp-vs-mvvm/
- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/difference-between-mvc-mvp-mvvm-swapneel-salunkhe

It will be great if the reason is found on why that diverstiy of opinions on this topic happen.

Answer (score 1):

Execution cycle remains the same for all, you need to identify the action from a controller and return a view.

In the link you have provided supporting view also states its a compound pattern where there is planned strategy between model,view and controller to fulfill the request.